# no sound through HDMI port Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: audio, hdmi

I have this version of ubuntu:

```
lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

And my laptop is

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-version

Lenovo ideapad 320-15ABR
```

I have no sound through HDMI even though the laptop sounds fine, and the sound when I connect through HDMI keeps being from the laptop speakers.

How should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Appears to be a known bug that can be easily fixed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403575/hdmi-audio-issue-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Dumb question: Have you selected the HDMI output? It's not automatic.